# Not understand the code of action and dispatch in this Redux tutorial

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm watching a tutorial about MERN stack project of a youtuber. And I'm watching him coding the Redux part of the project. There is some of his code which I don't understand
This is his Redux action code to retrieve data from api[image: Redux action]

From what I understand, this is an action and it supposed to return action object {type, payload}. I don't understand why he give an dispatch argument in the curly braces (line 4) and dispatch the action object (line 8)

This is his App.js file[image: When he call the dispatch action]

And in his App.js I dont see him pass any argument into getPosts() (line 16)

I try to create action using redux toolkit like this

```
export const getPosts = createAction('FETCH_ALL', async () => {

    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();

        return {
            payload: data,
        };

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }  
} )
```

Is there anything difference between my code and the image code
URL to the video : https://youtu.be/ngc9gnGgUdA?list=PL6QREj8te1P7VSwhrMf3D3Xt4V6_SRkhu&t=3130

Comment: link to the video?

Comment: ...you are recursively calling `getPosts`?

Comment: @youzef here is the url https://youtu.be/ngc9gnGgUdA?list=PL6QREj8te1P7VSwhrMf3D3Xt4V6_SRkhu&t=3128

Comment: @SurajRao My mistake. I am reading the redux toolkit createAction document. From what I think, recursively calling getPosts will add the payload given in argument braces
```
const increment = createAction('counter/increment')

let action = increment()
// { type: 'counter/increment' }

action = increment(3)
// returns { type: 'counter/increment', payload: 3 }
```

Comment: @SurajRao sorry for my mistake. I have fix my code

Comment: How is your action updating the store object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a thunk function from redux-thunk. A thunk function is a function that accepts two arguments: the Redux store dispatch method, and the Redux store getState method. Thunk functions are not directly called by application code. Instead, they are passed to store.dispatch():

```
const thunkFunction = (dispatch, getState) => {
  // logic here that can dispatch actions or read state
}

store.dispatch(thunkFunction)
```

Reference: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks